# How to add a directory located in a web server to iis as a virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, webserver

I'm working on an ASP MVC application . I want to add access to a folder located in a web server from IIS and I've permission to this web directory. I need to add this folder as a virtual directory in IIS in order to use `server.MapPath` to access to it from my application and I can't find how could I add a web direcory from IIS Manager all i find is how to add a physical path.

Comment: Which version of IIS?  the difference's between versions can be large.

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV I'm working with IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add virtual Directories in IIS7 in the Virtual Directories page in IIS Manager.  Microsoft has an article regarding that [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I've read this article and they just mentioned how to add " Physical path "

Comment: You have to do two steps: First you set up the alias, which is used to access via URL, then you have to set up the physical path where the directory will actually be located.  A IIS Virtual directory needs both of these.  See steps 5 and 6 in the article

Comment: I've done what is said in these steps , and now i need to add the link to the outside directory which is on the web

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you where connecting to an External Web Server.  There is [This Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308150/en-us) regarding creating a virtual directory to a folder on a remote computer, but it appears to be for IIS4-5.  Not sure if adding the UNC from the external server would work.